# ¿Cómo ejecutar un evento luego de cargar completamente un location.href en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

En el backend tengo un método que devuelve un archivo PDF usando el método GET, `HttpGet` para ser más exacto. Para acceder a este archivo tengo una función `location.href = "Url";` en donde especifico la URL y todo bien, el archivo se lanza al usuario.

El problema es que el usuario tiene un bonito modal que dice que espere y su espera puede ser mayor o menor, al margen de esto el modal sigue ahí. El tiempo de renderizado varía mucho, puede ser 3 segundos como pueden ser 30.

El siguiente código tiene un comportamiento by default para que cerrar el modal en 17500 milisegundos, dicho en otras palabras: 17,5 segundos.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ExportarPDF();" id="PDFdoc">
    <input type="button" id="btnFullPDF" value="Ejecutar Reporte" class="btn btn-info mostrarLoadingModal" />
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function ExportarPDF(){           
    var url = $("#magicButton").attr("href");
    console.log("url");
    console.log(url);
    location.href= url;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#modalLoading").modal('hide');
    },17500);
}
```

¿Cómo hago para saber en qué momento ese `location.href` ha terminado de cargar exitosamente? ¿Existe alguna otra manera? Conociendo esto puedo cerrar el modal justo en el tiempo en que el usuario tiene la ventanita de "Guardar archivo" y santo remedio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luego de andar jugando con diversas opciones, logré hacer una que se ajusta perfectamente a lo que busco, para ello, hice una variación del flujo original.

```
<div id="magicButton">
    <a href="#" onclick="ExportarPDF();" id="PDFdoc">
        <input type="button" id="btnFullPDF" value="Ejecutar Reporte" class="btn btn-info mostrarLoadingModal" />
    </a>
</div>
<div id="magicframe" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Desde otra función defino la URL con todos sus parámetros y le asigno un atributo `href` al `div` "magicButton" (sí, al div, esta es una flexibilidad del HTML para hacer cosas raras que funcionan), para que tengan una idea, en la función está la siguiente línea:

```
$("#magicButton").attr("href", aquiLaUrlGeneradaDinamicamente);
```

Y en el Javascript

```
function ExportarPDF(){           
    var url = $("#magicButton").attr("href");
    console.log("url");
    console.log(url);

    //Aqui verifico si existe el elemento 
    //y de ser cierto, elimino dicho elemento 
    //para evitar posibles errores.
    var existeReportePDFDiv = $("#ReportePDF").length > 0;
    if (existeReportePDFDiv ) {
       $("#ReportePDF").remove();
    }

    //Aqui está la magia: Solucionado con un iframe y jQuery con su método load
    $("<iframe />", { id: "ReportePDF"}).attr("src", url).appendTo('#magicframe');
    $("#ReportePDF").load(function () {
        //Este es el modal del clásico: "Loading Please Wait"
        $("#modalLoading").modal('hide');                
    });
}
```