# Detectar cuando un iframe termina de cargar

Tags: javascript, iframe

Construyo un menú de forma dinámica y cargo las diferentes opciones del menú en un *iframe*.

**Problema**: tengo opciones que tardan más en cargar que otras (esto depende claro de la cantidad de data que cargue la opción).

Como otro dato: tengo [block-ui](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) para bloquear peticiones AJAX en mi aplicación, y funciona bastante bien, bloqueo el inicio de una petición AJAX mostrando un mensaje de espera y libero cuando la petición retorna un valor. Esta es la idea que quiero lograr con el *iframe*

¿Que necesito?

-Conozco el momento cuando el *iframe* esta cargando, no es problema.-Aquí bloqueo la pantalla, pero no se cuando liberarla.

Necesito un evento en *JavaScript* que me ayude a identificar el momento en que el *iframe* termina de cargar.

Este es el *iframe*:

```
<iframe id="mainFrame" name="mainFrame" onunload="desbloquear();" src="" width="900" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

El html del menú se construye con esta estrucura:

```
<a class='anchor' href='#' data-url='../" + row.PATH + "'><i class='" + row.ICON + "'></i><span style='white-space: normal'>" + row.NOMBRE + "</span>
```

Y el JavaScript que carga el *iframe*:

```
$(".anchor").each(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    el.click(function () {
        bloquear(); //Aquí bloqueo la pantalla
        $("#mainFrame").attr("src", el.data('url'));
        $("#mainFrame").attr("", );

    })
});
```

Tengo una función `desbloquear();`, obviamente no funciona colocando al final del JavaScript que carga el *iframe*, porque puede que tarde en cargar y es lo que no logro detectar.

Comment: Prueba a crear una función que colocarás antes de llamar al iframe: `function frameLoaded () { alert ("iFrame cargado. Puedes llamar otra función ahora"); }`, luego le pones una etiqueta `onload` al iframe que llame a dicha función:  `<iframe onload="frameLoaded()" id="mainFrame" name="mainFrame" src... >`

Comment: Excelente @A.Cedano me funciono, gracias.

Comment: Quizás esto te sea de utilidad: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155362/c%c3%b3mo-ejecutar-un-evento-luego-de-cargar-completamente-un-location-href-en-javas es un escenario parecido

Comment: Por cierto, cuando tengas funcionando la recomendación del buen @A.Cedano, puedes ser el héroe de muchos usuarios al redactar la respuesta que utilizaste y marcarla como aceptada para ayudar a mantener la buena salud del sitio :D

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx excelente!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solución:

Tome la respuesta de A. Cedano:

1) Cree una función `frameLoaded`

```
function frameLoaded() {
    desbloquear(); //Esta función desbloquea la pantalla
}
```

2) Agregue el evento `onload` en el iframe

```
<iframe onload="frameLoaded();" id="mainFrame" name="mainFrame" src="" width="900" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Listo!