# Export archivo pdf usando ajax en MVC C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Me gustaría saber como se puede exportar un archivo excel usando ajax, he intentando de la siguiente manera, pero no resulta:

```
$("#ajax_loader").css("display", "");
        var formato = "PDF";

        //window.location.href = url;
        //$("#ajax_loader").hide();
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("format", formato);
        fd.append("nombreObra", $('#nombre_obra').val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%= Url.Action("Export", "Obras")%>',
            data: fd,
            DataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#ajax_loader").hide();
            }
        });
 });
```

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, se lo agradecería mucho.
Saludos.

Comment: Esto te podría dar una idea: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155362/c%c3%b3mo-ejecutar-un-evento-luego-de-cargar-completamente-un-location-href-en-javas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La generacion de un pdf debes realizarla del lado del servidor, en el codigo que has puesto invocas un action del controller de asp.net mvc, pero no es encesario enviar ningun `FormData` solo debes enviar un json simple

El tema no es como invocar el action ya que con el $.ajax puedes hacerlo sin problemas, sino como recibes el pdf que se genera en el servidor

El articulo describe una forma posible

[Generate and Download PDF file on Ajax Post method, C#](http://blog.prakashrathod.com/2016/12/22/generate-and-download-pdf-file-on-ajax-post-method-c/)

la idea es que usando ajax invoques un action del controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save()
    {

        // write code here to save the data in database. 
        var fName = string.Format("MYPDF-{0}.pdf", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 15, 15))
            {
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
                document.Open();
                document.Add(new Paragraph("HelloWorld"));
                document.Close();
            }

            var bytes = ms.ToArray();              
            Session[fName] = bytes;
        }

        return Json(new { success = true, fName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //return View();
    }
     public ActionResult DownloadInvoice(string fName)
     {
         var ms =  Session[fName] as byte[] ;
         if(ms == null)
             return new EmptyResult();
         Session[fName] = null;
         return File(ms, "application/octet-stream", fName);
     }
```

para que desde el cliente uses

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: "/home/save",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (resultData)
         {
             if (resultData.success) {
                window.location = "/home/DownloadInvoice" + "?fName=" + resultData.fName;
             }
         }
    });
 })
```

al usar el window.location realizar el download del pdf que esta temporalmente en la Session