# Descargar archivos con FileResult ajax c# mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, api, mvc

mi problema es que no se como retornar un archivo a la vista con ajax, cabe resaltar que el archivo es de .zip o .rar.

Este es el codigo de mi cotrolador:

```
[HttpGet]
        public FileResult DownloadPDF(string ruta)
        {
            //using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ruta))
            //{
            //    var currentPath = @"E:\XTrategia";
            //    zip.ExtractAll(currentPath);
            //    zip.Dispose();
            //}

            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ruta);
            string fileName = "MyFileDescargadoPDF.zip";
            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
        }
```

este es el codigo de mi ajax:
La variable uri, me trae la ruta fisica del archivo a descargar. es una ruta absoluta del servidor.

```
function exportar(uri) {
    var urlAdd = "Documento/DownloadPDF";
    var raiz = document.getElementById("hdfOculto").value;
    console.log(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + raiz + urlAdd);
    var urlAbsoluta = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + raiz + urlAdd;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlAbsoluta,
        data: { ruta: uri },
        success: function (res) {
            alert(res);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Cuando le mandas un GET desde el navegador con la ruta determinada, ¿qué ocurre? Por otro lado, aquí unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Me devolve el archivo en bits, cuando mando un console.log de respuesta me manda algo como este en la consola: (PK) . si llamo al controlador y su acción desde el navegaor me descargar, pero si llamo desde el ajax me manda en bits.

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes una forma: Hacer que el resultado abra una ubicación a nivel de location.

```
function exportar(uri) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlAbsoluta,
        data: { ruta: uri },
        success: function () {
            window.location = '@Url.Action("DownloadPDF", "Documento", new { ruta= rutaDelArchivoQueVaAIrEnLaURL })';
        }
    });    
}
```

Si deseas otra forma, también podrías usar un iframe, aquí te cuento cómo: [¿Cómo ejecutar un evento luego de cargar completamente un location.href en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/155362/822)