# Error al descargar zip con ajax MVC c#

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, zip

Tengo un proyecto en el cual genero un archivo zip en el servidor y posteriormente intento descargarlo al navegador del usuario que lo solicita.

Se genera el archivo zip correctamente pero al momento de devolverlo al ajax se descarga con error e incluso el archivo pesa aun más que el original.

Básicamente en el controller devuelve un objeto de tipo Fileresult con se ve a continuación.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en el ajax se obtengo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el archivo que se descarga siempre viene dañado y pesa el triple que el original del servidor.

Comment: ¿Has intentado abrirlo en otra pestaña? Me late que el problema está en el type del javascript. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor no dejes capturas es preferible que subas tu codigo.

Comment: por experiencia cuando hago eso solo paso la url del archivo por json y en el js le digo a un iframe que src es el archivo, es mas rapido y no mete tanto problema.

Comment: lo intentaré como indicas con el iframe

Comment: Ese escenario ya fue resuelto en esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/155362/822 Saludos.